# error installing ros noetic in step 1.5

Tags: ros-melodic, ubuntu, ros-noetic, bashrc

I installed ros noetic according to the instructions but when i get to `source ~/.bashrc` I get a message saying `bash: /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash: No such file or directory`.
What should i do next to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've copied a command from a different version of ROS documentation.
In the title you say you're installing ROS noetic, but sourcing ROS melodic.  For noetic use http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu

Please go into your *.bashrc* file and change the path to `/opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash`, save it and try to source again using `source ~/.bashrc`.